# How can I limit the result set of gulp.src to give only X number of files?

Tags: gulp

In a directory I have the following files:

```
1.whatIneed
2.whatIneed
3.whatIneed
4.whatIneed
5.whatIneed
6.whatIneed
7.whatIneed
8.whatIneed
9.whatIneed
10.whatIneed
```

I know that gulp.src will get all of those files, which is fine.

```
gulp.src("./files/*.whatIneed")
```

I additionally pipe gulp-sort into this to reverse the order. gSort is my defined constant for require("gulp-sort");

```
gulp.src("./files/*.whatIneed").pipe(gSort({asc: false}))
```

This does what I need and reverses the order of the file list.

```
10.whatIneed
9.whatIneed
8.whatIneed
7.whatIneed
6.whatIneed
5.whatIneed
4.whatIneed
3.whatIneed
2.whatIneed
1.whatIneed
```

**This is where I am stuck**. I want to limit that list now to only use the top X number of results to limit my list to this:

```
10.whatIneed
9.whatIneed
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are your files literally named with the numbers and you just want the two highest?  Or after some custom sort you want the first two listed?

Comment: They are all numerical - makes it easiest for trying to grab highest X numbers for one section of a page and then blast em all to a longer version elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this solved with additional trial and error along with some friends helping out.

By using glob - I was able to turn the file list into a native js array. Then slice and reverse accordingly.

```
glob.sync(files_needed_path).slice(-3).reverse();
```